# law of diminishing marginal returns and regression on the factors of production

Tags: microeconomics, econometrics, applied-econometrics

Does it make any sense to create an equation with

Profit ~ Production factor1 + Production factor1 ^ 2 + Production factor2 + Production factor2 ^ 2

to explain how much the increase of 1 in a company's production factors influences its profit? The idea is to derive and equal to zero and find the amount of production factor that maximizes profit. The function will have this format:

[image: the function will have this format]

```
# some R code 
#Regression Approach
{
 dat<-data.frame(profit=c(6000,9000,11080,12000,15010,14515,12000,11000,9000),
                factorP1=c(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
                factorP2=c(0,0,40,50,70,70,80,90,100))

  d<-lm(dat[,1]~dat[,2]+I(dat[,2]^2)+dat[,3]+I(dat[,3]^2))#,data = dat) 
 plot(dat$profit,xlab="Production Factor",ylab="profit")
    lines(predict(d),col="blue",lwd = 2)
    legend(3,0.5*max(dat[,1]), legend=c("Linear"),
           col=c("blue"), lty=1:2, cex=0.8,
           title="Model", text.font=4, bg='lightblue') 
  library(MLmetrics)

  print("MEAN ABSOLUTE PERCETAGE ERROR")
  print(   MAPE(predict(d),dat$profit))
  #library(car)  
  #vif(d)#Multi-collinearity
  #library(lmtest)
  coe<-coef(d) 
  coe[is.na(coe)]<-0          
  company<-optim(c(0,0),function(x){coe[1] +coe[2]*x[1]+coe[3]*x[1]^2 +coe[4]*x[2]+coe[5]*x[2]^2}, control=list(fnscale=-1),
                 upper=c(9999,9999),lower=c(0,0)) # linear
  
  names(company$par)= names(dat[-1])
  print(company$par)
  names(company$value)= "profit"
  print(company$value)
} #end of regression approach

# Trial and Error approach
#the company grows its database by trial and error and just:

dat[which.max(dat$profit),]
```

is there an error with regression approach? is this how companies plan their growth?

Comment: No this would have several problems - you are regressing profit only on factor inputs but there are likely other things that affect company’s profit such as for example price you charge for your product - so this as a profit function would be incomplete. Other issue is how will you ever collect all data on different input-profit combinations - that would require the firm on purpose produce some even obviously suboptimal quantity of products in some periods just to generate data. How firms determined the amount of inputs that maximize profit varies from industrious to industry so that part of Q

Comment: Is too broad. The profit function is also most likely not stable over time but constantly changes. Many firms will just try to maximize profit just by trial or error. Some business for sure do some numerical simulations or forecasts based on past performance and so on but I can’t imagine a business trying to actually estimate its own profit function using some simple regression like you suggest in your post and then just use calculus to determine optimum quantity.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i understood the first problem, but think with me the price of the service changes but the cost of the company with the production factor does not change, wouldn't the regression adjust? I understood the second problem and I totally agree, so [companies](https://www.forbes.com/global2000/#7da5819b335d) simply go through trial and error, this is absurd I thought there would be some way to better quantify this

Comment: No how can regression adjust? The effect of price will be affecting regression somehow (as effect of all omitted variables in some way will) but not in any way that would somehow make the model ‘correct’ for any price. In fact it will just bias the coefficients for those factor inputs leading to wrong inference. Also some firms for sure hire data scientists to do quantitative modeling that helps them with decision making. For example, quantitative marketing nowadays syphons lot of econometric graduates who then build models to see how let’s say promotions are affecting Sales and then some

Comment: Some further forecasting of how that affects profit can be made. But it can’t really be done in a crude way how you suggest and most of this modeling is used to support decision making and for forecasting not necessary to itself just provide optimal use of factors and so on. If that would be possible most companies would be already run by computers.

Comment: but when i solve a prodution function with [langrangian](https://www.dummies.com/education/economics/how-to-use-the-langrangian-function-in-managerial-economics/)  with K as capital and L as laborwhat exactly im doing??

Comment: finding an analytical analytical solution to profit maximization problem. The problem with the above is not that you could not find maximum profit by optimizing profit function - the problem with above is that you can’t know what the profit function is based on the data you have and by fitting a regression through that data. If you would skip the estimation part and just assume some functional form for profit you can use lagrangian to solve the problem

Comment: so the langrangian approach just assume an arbitrary K^0.5 and L^0.5 ? with no data to fit this values??

Comment: it’s not completely arbitrary for example, prod function $AK^0.5L^0.5$ implies constant returns to scale which can be tested independently and if it is not satisfied different production can be used. But there is no way how to estimate exactly how production function looks like in real time, so you have to assume some. If you would want to do some historical analysis you could estimate what profit function was in the past but not with the sort of regression you have in your Q and also only approximately.

Comment: i'm really shocked

Comment: by what? How is this shocking? I mean how do you expect it would even be possible to estimate profit function in real time? That would require existence of parallel universes and being able to observe them

Comment: I expected an exact (or almost) way to estimate how much each factor of production contributes to a company's profit(imagine a company that has 12 factors of production in it, does it maximize profit just by guessing ??), assuming premises is the same as guessing.

Comment: IRL businesses do not generally set up lagrangians of profit functions. Profit optimization is done by some heuristic rules, or by trial and error or other strategies. These analytical profit optimization rules can describe firm action because IRL firms that fail to use profit maximizing heuristic etc will go out of business and only the ones that adopted the right rules will stay in there but that does not mean that the business owner even understand their rules (as a matter of fact profit maximizing behavior was even empirically observed in behavior of ducks that are barely self aware).